# How do I change the colours of multiple buttons, each into different ones when hovered?

Tags: html, css

I made a calculator using HTML and some JavaScript but I don't know how to change the colours of the buttons, each into a different one when hovered. Here is the code of one of the rows:

```
<input style="height:25px; width:40px;" type="button" class='btn btn-default btn-success btn-lg' name="one" value="!" OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '!'">
<input style="height:25px; width:40px;" type="button" class='btn btn-default btn-success btn-lg' name="two" value="@" OnCLick="Calc.Input.value += '@'">
<input style="height:25px; width:40px;" type="button" class='btn btn-default btn-success btn-lg' name="three" value="#" OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '#'">
<input style="height:25px; width:40px;" type="button" class='btn btn-default btn-success btn-lg' name="plus" value="+" OnClick="Calc.Input.value += ' + '">
```

Here is the CSS code which I used to change the colour of buttons when hovering:

```
.btn:hover {
background-image: none;
background-color: #ff69b4;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

It changes the colours of the buttons when hovered on, but I want to make each of them separate colours.

Comment: give each button an id, use the id in your CSS :hover rule selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can target each one using their `name` attribute:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/194yg00j/1/)

```
.btn[name="one"]:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.btn[name="two"]:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.btn[name="three"]:hover {
    background-color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.btn[name="plus"]:hover {
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to add additional class to each of them like this:

```
<input style="height:25px; width:40px;" type="button" class='btn btn-default btn-success btn-lg green' name="one" value="!" OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '!'">
<input style="height:25px; width:40px;" type="button" class='btn btn-default btn-success btn-lg yellow' name="two" value="@" OnCLick="Calc.Input.value += '@'">
<input style="height:25px; width:40px;" type="button" class='btn btn-default btn-success btn-lg orange' name="three" value="#" OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '#'">
<input style="height:25px; width:40px;" type="button" class='btn btn-default btn-success btn-lg blue' name="plus" value="+" OnClick="Calc.Input.value += ' + '">
```

and add this css for the new classes:

```
.green:hover{
    background-color: green;
}
.blue:hover{
    background-color: blue;
}
.yellow:hover{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.orange:hover{
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set each button up as a separate class, which can inherit from btn:hover, and then just change the details you want. i.e.

```
<input style="height:25px; width:40px;" type="button" class='btn btn-default btn-success btn-lg btn1' name="one" value="!" OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '!'">
<input style="height:25px; width:40px;" type="button" class='btn btn-default btn-success btn-lg btn2' name="two" value="@" OnCLick="Calc.Input.value += '@'">
```

and then for the CSS:

```
.btn1:hover {
background-image: none;
background-color: #ff69b4;
font-weight: bold;
}
.btn2:hover {
background-image: none;
background-color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you prefer keeping your CSS uniform, is adding an HTML attribute on each button as such:

```
<button ... hovercc="#1155ff" ...></button>
```

Then you can use the value in the CSS:

```
.btn:hover {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: attr(hovercc, color);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Note this isn't standardized, and may not work on all browsers, even modern, but is worth testing.